# SSRS set date time parameter to today but available values to be any date

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that requires an end date, as this could be any time in the last 3 years I have left the parameter available values as None - this allows users to choose the date using the date picker.  However so I can run a snapshot, I would also like to set the default value to yesterday which I can do with the following expression =DateAdd("d",-1,Today()). But when I try to snapshot the report I'm not able to as it seems the available values need to be populated, any help much appreciated so that users who wish to change the default can do so using the calendar date picker.

Comment: So you set the parameter type as Date/Time?.. Can you post a screenshot of the parameters?

Comment: I cant seem to add a screen shot, but the General parameters are: Data type - Date/Time, Visibility set to visible.  Available Values set to None, Default values - Get value from a query =DateAdd("d",-1,Today())

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using "Get value from a query"... Instead, use "Specify value", then put that expression in - `=DateAdd("d",-1,Today())`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is but if you want to add the available date values to see if it fixes the problem with the snapshot, you can use some recursion in a CTE:

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT * 
FROM GETDATES 
ORDER BY THEDATE DESC 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Ive tried running this but it brings back a list of dates rather than the date picker calendar view thats required, but is very useful and will be using it for other reports